# Visual Studio certificate error "the manifest designer could not import the certificate": What is the reason?

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, certificate, msix, winui-3

I am currently developing a WinUI 3 application, but I believe the details of the application type are not that important for the question I have.

The application comes with a "Package project" for publishing the application using MSIX:

[image]

In the  editor for the "Package.appxmanifest" file in the package project there is a "Packaging" tab that has a "Choose certificate" button for selecting a ".pfx" certificate file.

**How I obtained the ".pfx" file:**
My IT department logged onto my machine while the application for the windows certificate store was open. There we added a new "Code signing" certicate under "Own certicates", but which is not issued by me, but by the IT department. They told me that this certicate should also be trusted by client machines, when I publish applications signed with it, because it was issued by them and so it has a valid trust chain. Later I exported a pfx file based on that certicate which I am trying to use now.

Now, upon selecting this .pfx file in Visual Studio on the 'Packaging' tab, I get this error message:

[image]

Unfortunately the "The manifest designer could not import the certificate" error message does not come with the exact reason what the problem is.

I am quite sure that my certificate has a valid date and also is made for "Code signing".

I already found out that there are other users wondering about how to fix the certificate if this message appears. But nobody seems to know **how to get told about the exact problem**.
Is there some way I can use Visual Studio or Powershell or some other tool to tell me what the exact problem is for the certificate when I select it in Visual Studio and this error appears? I would like to have more detailed information than "there is something wrong with the exported .pfx certificate" that I can give to my IT department.

I am aware that I can specify this setting in the project file of the packing project in order to stop the error from appearing:

```
<EnableSigningChecks>false</EnableSigningChecks>
```

But I would also be very interested to know what the exact problem is. Thank you.

**Additional information:**
To check the pfx certicate file, I also executed the "certutil" command (with the -v option) as indicated here: https://superuser.com/a/580698/543294 In the large text dump file I find an issuer that I also find in the list of Trusted Root Certification Authorities of the certicate management application.

Comment: Did you edit the Publisher attribute of the `<Identity>` element in your `Package.appxmanifest` to match the Subject property of the certificate?

Comment: On the 'Packaging' tab, there is a TextBox next to a "Publisher" label. The content of the TextBox is "E=MYEMAIL" and this TextBox is greyed out / disabled, so I guess it is not meant to be changed and was filled based on the selected certificate. The value of the <Identiy> element in the Package.appxmanifest  file the same as in the TextBox. However, as indicated in my question, I am looking for way for the system to tell my about the problem.

Comment: I did not properly explain how I obtained the .pfx file in the first version of my question, sorry for that. I added a new section "How I obtained the ".pfx" file".

Comment: Hi @mm8, where is/where can I find the 'Subject' property of of the certificate?  I also have a certificate from IT, that I am trying to use to sign my package.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

> Did you edit the Publisher attribute of the  element in your Package.appxmanifest to match the Subject property of the certificate?

This should not generate the error above. In the worst case, it could let you build the package and then fail to install it due to this mismatch, or it could fail to build the package.

What I suspect is that IT gave you a code signing certificate that they generated (instead of buying it from a certified vendor). This is perfectly fine if you plan to deploy your application only internally, inside your company, as they can deploy that certificate to all other machines from the company, so those machines trust it.

However, if the certificate was indeed generated by IT, and they didn't deployed yet to your machine, VS might see this is not a trusted certificate and could give this error.

You can check if the certificate is trusted by opening certmgr console and searching for the certificate in the **Trusted Root Certification Authorities** hive.

If it is not there, double click the PFX file and [follow the wizard](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/install-test-certificate-from-msix.html) (from steps #4) to install it.

Comment: I think I did not explain correctly how I got the certificate, sorry. What happended is that they logged onto  my machine while the application for the windows certificate store was open. There we added a new "Code signing" certicate under "Own certicates", but which is not issued by me, but by the IT department. Later I exported a pfx file based on that certicate which I am trying to use now. I will change the question description now. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I executed the "certutil" command (with the -v option)  as indicated here: https://superuser.com/a/580698/543294   In the large text dump file I find an issuer that I also find in the list of Trusted Root Certification Authorities. It that what you are refering to?